# Получение и передача ссылки с редиректом

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! Использую в своем проекте плеер `com.github.khizar1556.MKVideoPlayer:mkvideoplayer:0.1.5`
вставлял в него ссылку mp3 напрямую `sate.com/audio.mp3` и все прекрасно работает. Но я вытягиваю ссылки mp3 через API. API дает ссылки такого типа: `sate.com/a/audio/` и есть по ней перейти то происходит редирект по ссылке типа `sate.com/audio.mp3`. Вот почему-то медиа плеер не может определить ссылку которая идет после редиректа, и он выдает ошибку. Получаю я ссылку с помощью файла адаптера и `audio = intent.getStringExtra("audio");` и потом передаю в плеер `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(audio));` Как можно обойти данную проблему? Может быть есть способ передать ссылку в медиа плеер после редиректа? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить таким способом

```
audio = intent.getStringExtra("audio");
url1 = new URL(audio);
String str_audio = new String(String.valueOf(url1));
url2 = new URL(str_audio);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(url2)));
```

Может быть кто-то знает что-то попроще, а то это какой-то... :D Но на удивление работает очень быстро) аудио по 40мин грузит за секунду.